# Examples of how abstract algebra is used to find concrete solutions to a mathematical model?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

All references I've seen to abstract algebra show how it helps in the *representation* of mathematical models...are there any examples of using abstract algebra to calculate actual solutions to a problem (ie get a concrete function or number?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question strikes me as very odd because abstract algebra isn't by its nature a set of tools for problem solving -- it's a description of a very broad area of mathematics full of its own questions and answers.  Abstract algebra is much more akin to something like geometry or number theory than it is to something like calculus or linear algebra, so asking "What problems does this help us to solve?" or "What does this help us to calculate?" isn't the right frame of mind to have when approaching the subject.  Instead, you should be asking "What is this subject about, and why is that important?"

I think the analogy with geometry is a good one.  Geometry is for the most part a self-contained subject, in that most of the techniques in geometry are only useful for solving problems in geometry.  But at the same time, geometry is an extremely useful subject, because *geometric objects arise naturally in a variety of contexts*.  Abstract algebra is the same way -- groups, rings, fields, and so forth arise naturally in a variety of contexts, so knowing something about these objects can be enormously helpful.

That being said, there are of course a large number of techniques within abstract algebra that are useful for specific computations.  However, first abstract algebra courses tend to be much more concerned with covering the basics of a subject and getting students used to all of the standard algebraic structures, so  there usually isn't much time for covering computation techniques.  One notable exception is [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), which can be covered shortly after learning about permutation groups and is incredibly useful for exploiting symmetry in counting problems.  But for real computational power, you have to learn something about one of the many specific subjects within abstract algebra, e.g. representation theory, commutative algebra, Galois theory, homological algebra, algebraic number theory, and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer...I had a suspicion that this is why I couldn't find such answers out there. Your answer clearly explains why :-) thanks again!